# How to access power BI Service in multi tenant scenario

Tags: powerbi, multi-tenant

I have my own Power BI Pro account from my company powerbi@mycompany.com.
My client has given me access to his tenant as an external guest user with one of it's Power BI Pro licenses.

The question is: how do I access the Power BI Service of my client? When I connect to the service I can't find any possible way to switch then tenant from one to another with the same account (like you can on the Azure portal).

Comment: Q: Are you writing a new Power BI app for your client?  Q: Where is the app hosted: on your account, or on your client's account?

Comment: everything is on the client tenant

Answer (score 13):

If you are a guest in some host's tenant (domain) then you need their CTID to log in to that host instance. The CTID is the tenant identifier of the host's Azure Active Directory. They can look this up for you in the Azure Portal or use the shortcut below to get it from their PowerBI service. If the host can't find their CTID for some reason you can look it up here: [Tenant ID Lookup by Domain](https://gettenantpartitionweb.azurewebsites.net/). Once you have the tenant id (CTID), simply provide it to the url [PowerBI CTID Url](https://app.powerbi.com/home?ctid=%3Chost%27s%20tenant%20id%3E) :

https://app.powerbi.com/home?ctid=<host's tenant id (ctid)>

and then this will sign you in to their (the Host's) PowerBI.

Click the ? and go to About PowerBI to bring up the window shown below.

[image: PowerBI CTID]

For PowerBI Desktop, you need to sign out and then sign back in again. When signing in, click the Sign in Options where you can then elect to sign in to an organization. Provide the Host's domain name and continue the sign in process. Now you will be signed in to PowerBI Desktop and PowerBI service - ready to build, publish and view reports in your Host's organization.

[image: Sign in Options]

I hope that all makes sense! :)

Comment: I had to first type in an incorrect mail address for sign in, otherwise the sign in window with the sign-in options did not show up at all. After that everything worked just as described!

Comment: This worked for me today as well - this really should be more straightforward in Power BI tbh

Comment: Cant agree more @KevinLawrence - thats why I wrote a pretty post explaining it :D

Comment: I have a license in my "home" tenant, and a license in another tenant. When I try to sign in to PowerBI desktop, it doesn't let me publish/work on the other tenant. I need seperate accounts for this.

Answer (score 1):

It would be even better if you could switch tenants without the URL.  Someone posted that idea on Power BI's site and you can upvote it.

https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=eb9194f1-ceea-41a7-9761-76e913c58ed5

Answer (score 0):

This is all explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/whitepaper-azure-b2b-power-bi#enabling-external-users-to-edit-and-manage-content-within-power-bi

Including the url you need to use to access your customer’s tenant.  And you don’t need your customer to assign a pro license if you have one in your home tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that you can actually redirect someone directly to the App that you are creating in the workspace. This can be quite handy if you want to redirect someone directly to the report app instead of the home page.

[Go to "update App"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52X3v.png)

[Then go to the permissions Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK6pf.png)

[Copy and PAste the link from the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyE9P.png)

The link to the app contains the tenant ID

Hope that works! :)