# Accessing Azure Fabric in a Multi-Tenant Scenario

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, microsoft-fabric

I am facing an issue with tenant switching in Microsoft Fabric. My primary Azure account, associated with my home tenant, does not have a Fabric license. However, I was invited to a different tenant as a guest user with the same account and assigned the role of a Fabric administrator.

The problem arises when trying to access Fabric in the new tenant:

While I can switch tenants in the Azure portal, there is no direct link or option to access Fabric from the portal interface.

1. Within Fabric itself, I couldn't find any feature or setting that allows for tenant switching.
2. This issue seems similar to a previously discussed scenario for PowerBI ([How to access power BI Service in multi tenant scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67376837/how-to-access-power-bi-service-in-multi-tenant-scenario)), but the equivalent URL didn't work for Fabric.

How can I access Fabric in the context of the new tenant where I am an administrator? Any guidance or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "but the equivalent URL didn't work for Fabric." It should, and does for me.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try the following?

```
https://app.fabric.microsoft.com/home?ctid=<your_tenant_id>?
```

Comment: Yes.  Either the Fabric link or the normal Power BI link with the Tenant ID will work.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?